# html5 header tags, anchor tags in nav tags are unusual/undesired height

Tags: css, html, header, anchor, nav

I've been trying format a new webpage header/nav bar with the html5 mark-up. I'm having difficulties getting my css to format things correctly. Using divs and tables I was able to produce the following:

[image: How I want it to look]

*I want to produce the above image without using divs or tables, the following is a summary of my attempt that didn't work. I believe my understanding of `display:table-cell` is missing something.*

Changing to the html below and using the following css attributes `display:table`,`display:table-row`,`display:table-cell`,ect. is causing an undesired anchor height - I poked around with some dev tools and I'm fairly certain the anchor height is the issue. (complete css is on this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjQKe/1/)):

```
<header>
<nav>
    <img class="logo" src="img.png"/>
    <a href=""><h1>Home</h1></a>
    <a href=""><h1>Blog</h1></a>
    <a href=""><h1>About</h1></a>
    <a href=""><h1>Contact</h1></a>
</nav>
</header>
```

[image: current results]

trying to set the anchor and header tag `max-height:100px` didn't work (along with a handful of other attempts), it keeps getting computed to ~130px.

Please see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjQKe/1/) for the code.

Comment: Why does this have to be done using tables instead of regular display types like block, and inline-block?

Comment: @Unipartisandev i guess he wants to do it this way to get those vertical lines

Comment: I want to keep the four anchor tags/h1 tags symmetrical in width but able to be wider or narrower as the page width expands/shrinks. do you know a trick for me to do this with block and inline-block?

Comment: So what you're asking is if there is a way to make all of those parts size or "scale" with each other on different screen resolutions, or are you talking about when someone zooms in and out of a page?  Have you ever tried sizing your page with em instead of px?

Comment: If what I am seeing in the JsFiddle is with tables, it looks like it does exactly what display:block/inline-block plus em and percentage of course, sizing does.  I just noticed that you changed the default font-size so that may break it actually.

Comment: I'm not opposed to display:block/inline-block. I had the layout originally with a table element and was trying to reproduce it with the html5 tags. If you have a solution to produce the desired layout (first image in question) by all means please post, I would like to see where I am missing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace your CSS with mine

```
nav h1{
    color:lightgray;
    font-size: 150%;
    border-left:2px solid whitesmoke;
    padding:0px;
    min-width:50px;
    padding-right:30px;
}
nav a{
   float:left;
    width:20%;
    max-height:100px;
}
nav a h1:hover{
    color:lime;
}
nav{
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000000;

}
header{
    background-color:black;
    background-position:-50px 0px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    max-height:100px;
}
header img.logo{
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:430px;
    float:left;
}
```

key is to add `float:left` instead of using `display:table,display:table-row,display:table-cell`

Comment: Thank you Fibericon and Aditya! good call with the floating, definitely fixed my issue (and looks like less of a headache)

Comment: Is there a way to have the anchor tags always scale over the width of the page in compliment with the logo with float? (as if it was a table row)

Comment: @ArtyMcFly its better if you ask another question for that arty and explain what you want to say

Answer (score 1):

The extra 30px is coming from the 15px padding on the h1 tags as padding is not included in the max-height

Comment: I just tried setting the padding to to 0px but it didn't fix my issue [fiddle - update](http://jsfiddle.net/jjQKe/2/) thank you for the suggestion =]

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Solution

**and explanation using `display:table`,`display:table-row`,`display:table-cell`**

Alternatively I figured out what was causing the obscure height. when using `table`, `tr`, and `td` tags the max-height of the table-cell (`td`) was never overwritten.

When I changed the tags to `header`,`nav` elements the anchor tag, even thought it had `display:table-cell` and `max-height:100px` was still allowing the height to be overwritten, by it's internal contents, the h1 tag. The h1's margin was causing the height of the anchor tag to be higher than desired. I resolved the issue by setting `margin:0px` of the h1 tag.

Using float it caused the anchor tags to re-render below the logo. I wanted it to stay in scale in the same line. I didn't specify this is my question, so I'm leaving the previous selected answer selected.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjQKe/14/) shows I can widen/narrow the page and keep the navigation elements scaled and spread out accordingly.